# querying for multiple records by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got few tables like this:

Color

```
id      Color_Name
---    -------
 1      RED
 2      GREEN
```

Color_Shades

```
id      ColorId    ShadeId    date_created
---     -------    -------   --------------
 1       1          55        03/15/2013
 2       1          43        02/01/2012
 3       2          13        05/15/2011
 4       2          15        06/11/2009
```

I'm trying to get a list of all distinct colors with their latest date.

I tried

```
SELECT a.Color_Name, b.date_created FROM Color a, Color_Shades b
WHERE a.id = b.ColorId
```

but this is giving me mixed results.

My desired results are:

```
 Color_Name   date_created
----------    ---------------
 RED              03/15/2013
 GREEN            05/15/2011
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are near to what you need. You just need to aggregate those columns using `MAX` to get theor latest date.

```
SELECT  a.Color_name, MAX(b.date_created) date_created
FROM    Color a
        INNER JOIN Color_shades b
            ON a.id = b.colorID
GROUP   BY a.Color_Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16c9e/1)